# como puedo usar el metodo lastInsertId() estando en otra clase. PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

lo que pasa es que debido a que quiero saber el último ID de la inserción y para eso está el metodo lastInsertId(), pero lo que pasa es que ese está en otra clase a parte.

Lo que quiero hacer es una inserción a una tabla que a su vez tiene una relacion con otras trablas y para eso necesito el id cuando se haga el insert

Clase A: está la conexión a mi base de datos
Clase B: está el insert

```html
<?php
class claseA{


  public static function invocarPDOrigen(){
 
    $connection = "mysql:host=localhost; dbname=basededatos; charset=utf8mb4";
    $pdo = new PDO($connection, 'root', '');
    return $pdo;
  }

}



class ClaseB{

            
            /*Si hago la conexión aqui, sí me funciona y me muestra el valor (Pero esa no es la idea)*/

              //$connection = "mysql:host=localhost; dbname=basededatos; charset=utf8mb4";
              //$pdo = new PDO($connection, 'root', '');

            /*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

            function resultado(){
              $instanClase=new claseA();

              $query = $instanClase::invocarPDOrigen()->prepare("INSERT INTO tablatest (test) VALUES (:test)");
              $query->execute(['test' => 'dato']);
        
              return $instanClase::invocarPDOrigen()->lastInsertId(); //Al hacerlo con otra clase me retorna un 0
            }
}

$mostrar=new ClaseB();
$mostrar->resultado();

?>
```

solo me funciona si pongo la conexion de la base de datos a la claseB directamente (y esa no es la idea)

Comment: hola @BetaM ya lo corregí. Igual me darías una ayudita? porfa

Comment: Siiiii, me funcionó, gracias bro!!! :)))